# Aggregate rows of Spark DataFrame to String after groupby

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm quite new both Spark and Scale and could really need a hint to solve my problem. So I have two DataFrames A (columns id and name) and B (columns id and text) would like to join them, group by id and combine all rows of text into a single String:

A

```
+--------+--------+
|      id|    name|
+--------+--------+
|       0|       A|
|       1|       B|
+--------+--------+
```

B

```
+--------+ -------+
|      id|    text|
+--------+--------+
|       0|     one|
|       0|     two|
|       1|   three|
|       1|    four|
+--------+--------+
```

desired result:

```
+--------+--------+----------+
|      id|    name|     texts|
+--------+--------+----------+
|       0|       A|   one two|
|       1|       B|three four|
+--------+--------+----------+
```

So far I'm trying the following:

```
var C = A.join(B, "id")
var D = C.groupBy("id", "name").agg(collect_list("text") as "texts")
```

This works quite well besides that my texts column is an Array of Strings instead of a String. I would appreciate some help very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am just adding some minor functions in yours to give the right solution, which is

```
A.join(B, Seq("id"), "left").orderBy("id").groupBy("id", "name").agg(concat_ws(" ", collect_list("text")) as "texts")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

```
val bCollected = b.groupBy('id).agg(collect_list('text).as("texts")
val ab = a.join(bCollected, a("id") == bCollected("id"), "left")
```

First DataFrame is immediate result, b DataFrame that has texts collected for every id. Then you are joining it with a. bCollected should be smaller that b itself, so it will *probably* get better shuffle time

Comment: This question has a dupe somewhere.