# Pyspark / Spark: Drop groups that don't contain a certain value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

I need your help with a Spark/Pyspark question. I have a Spark DataFrame which looks like this. I want to group the dataframe by the `name` column. How can I only keep those groups that contain at least one `nickname` 'X'?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["A", "A", "B" ,"B", "C", "C"],
                   "nickname":["X","Y","X","Z","Y", "Y"]}
```

this question has been answered for Pandas with the `filter` function. However, Pyspark does not seem to support `groupBy().filter()`.

Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: This might give you an idea for aggregations of strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910306/aggregate-rows-of-spark-dataframe-to-string-after-groupby
You can use a .select("select X's') -> groupBy("on name") with this you should use .agg(cancat strings)

Comment: thanks for your reply! however, I don't want to aggregate, but keep only certain groups and drop the rest. I don't want to concatenate the strings as well

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.groupby('name','nickname').count().filter('Use condition which you want')
```